# Calling object and called object

Tags: python, oop

When we write `object1.method(object2)`, which is the calling object and which is the called object? Does it not mean that `method` is being called on `object1` (with argument `object2`)? Or is it simply that `object1` is the calling object and `object2` is the called object?

**Note** In response to a comment below, let me clarify that -

"calling object" means the object that is calling `method`. "called object" means the object on which `method` acts.

Comment: "Calling object" is not really a well-defined concept.

Comment: "Calling object" is the object that calls the `method`.

Comment: The "calling object" is passed implicitly as the first argument (e.g., as "self" in its class definition): `object1.method(object2)` is the same as `method(object1, object2)`.

Answer (score 2):

If this is part of the code of a method of an object called, say, `object3`, then one could say that `object3` is the "calling object", while `object1` is the "called object". `object2` is just an argument:

```
class Foo:
    def amethod():
        ...
        object1.method(object2)

...

object3 = Foo()
object3.amethod()
```

Comment: This is exactly what was on my mind. Thanks for clarifying and confirming.

Answer (score 1):

> When we write `object1.method(object2)`, which is the calling object and which is the called object?

Let's back up. *"calling object"* is not really a common term, and its very ambiguous. I think that's part of the reason you're getting confused.

When you write `object1.method(object2)` you are *calling* the method `method` of *object* `object1` and passing `object2` as *an argument* to the method. That's what's happening.

`object1` is not a "calling object". It is simply an object whose `method` attribute is being called. You can't call an object per se<sup>1</sup>. You could say instead `object1` is the *object* from which the `method` method is *called*. That'd be correct.

Likewise, `object2` is not the "called object". It's never called in anyway. It is simply passed as an argument to `object1.method()`. Here's a simple example of everything I said above:

```
>>> class Object:
...     def method(self, arg):
...         print("I'm just an argument", arg)
...     # This method is simply for pretty printing
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return 'object'
... 
>>> 
>>> # Here's object1. We'll call its method attribute and pass in
... # object2 as an argument.
... 
>>> object1 = Object()
>>> # Here's object2. It's only being passed as an argument.
... 
>>> object2 = Object()
>>> 
>>> # Here's the call
... 
>>> object1.method(object2)
I'm just an argument object
>>>
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Technically you *can* call an object, through something called [operator overloading](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html). But to avoid confusing you to much, just ignore that for now.</sub>

Comment: What I mean by "called object" is the object on which `method` acts. It is now clear to me that `method` acts on `object1` using `object2` as an argument. Thanks for your reply.